# how to send multiple parameter to selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

hello can anyone tell me how to send multiple parameter to selector. I have created one button programmatically and i want to send three parameters of that button selector. please help me.

below is the code which i wrote:

```
UIButton *addButtonObj = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[addButtonObj addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addButtonObj setTitle:component.componentValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`aMethod` is my method name and i want to send multiple parameter to this.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a target to your `UIButton`, there are three possibilities for passing data:

```
- (IBAction)aMethod;                                       // no data passed
- (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender;                            // passed sender obj
- (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;  // passed sender obj + event
```

You could give your button a tag and ask for it in your `aMethod:` method:

```
- (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender {

    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    if(theButton.tag == 42) {

        // call my fancy method with 3 params!
    }
 }
```

Maybe you should provide more details on what you're finally want to achieve :).

Best Regards,
Christian

Comment: On iOS, an action method can have three possible signatures: no parameter, a single parameter of type `id`, or two parameters of types `id` and `UIEvent *`; all three signatures having `void` as the return type.

Comment: Good point. Didn't know the last one (with `id` and `UIEvent`). Will edit my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but the target of a button action probably receives an id (usually named sender).

```
- (void) buttonPress:(id)sender;
```

Within the method call, sender should be the button in your case, allowing you to read properties such as it's name, tag, etc.